# Cannot return string from function Kotlin/Android Studio

Tags: android, function, kotlin, return

I have a button that calls a function:

```
    btnRegistrationRegister.setOnClickListener {

        val email = etRegistrationEmail.text.toString()
        val password = etRegistrationPassword.text.toString()

        registerUser(email, password)

        Log.d(TAG,uid)
```

And I have a function that returns the uid:

```
    fun registerUser(email:String,password:String):String{
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        var uid = "test"
        return uid
    }
```

The issue is I still cannot access the variable uid, for example in the next line

```
        Log.d(Tag,uid)
```

I realize this is pretty entry level stuff, so I'm obviously missing a key point here. uid is still "Unresolved reference error".

I'm trying to get the uid to use for the next function without nesting all my functions into one giant function.

Comment: `val uid = registerUser(email, password)`

Comment: thanks, so essentially, i need to declare it outside of the function as part of the function?  That makes sense I suppose.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function named registerUser returns a uid but you are not storing it anywhere. In order to use the uid you must store it or else if you do not need to store it then you should probably not return it from the method.

If you need to store it then just store it in a non-mutable variable like this :

```
val uid = registerUser(email, password)
```

If you dont want to store the uid and just want to print the log then you can use this:

```
registerUser(email, password).also { Log.d(Tag,it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `email:String,password:String` parameters in your `registerUser` function so, it must return two parameters as well.

Here;

```
var uid = "test"
  return uid
```

You are just returning `uid` so change it to two parameters as return then it will be fine to use:

```
val uid = registerUser(email, password)
  return uid
```